# Best practice for raising IOError exception in Python

Tags: python, exception, errno

I am writing a small Python interface for reading temperatures from a DS18B20 Sensor via sysfs. Besides the temperature also a status of a CRC sum can be read. To trigger a CRC error, I decided to utilize `IOError`:

```
sn = "28-000005589697"  # sensor serial number
# file containing information of temperature and if CRC is valid: 
fname = "sys/bus/w1/devices/" + sn + "/w1_slave"
with open(fname, 'f') as f: 
...
raise IOError("Invalid CRC in {}!".format(sn))
```

As a far I understand `IOError`, it has the members `message`, `filename`, `errno` and `strerror`. By my approach only `message` is used. It seems like I am missing something here.

What is the best practice to raise an `IOError` exception, so it blends in well with other errors such as *disk full* or *file not found*, etc.?

Comment: You should not use an `IOError` because it's not an I/O problem (you _could_ read data), but an integrity one (what you read was incorrect or corrupted). Define `CRCError` or `IntegrityError` or whatever, instead.

Comment: @Stefano, It is probably the most straight forward solution. The next question is, does it make sense to derive a ``IntegrityError`` from ``BaseException`` or  ``EnvironmentError``, which is described by *The base class for exceptions that can occur outside the Python system*. I know this is all a bit philosophical, but I already ha a few hardware Projects, where I ended up with a quite cluttered error hierachy.

Answer (score 4):

You know `filename`, it is the file you were reading and calculating the CRC for. For `errno` and `strerror` I would pick from the list of defined errors in `libc`. This is where the reasons of most `IOErrors` originate from, so lets keep this implementation detail for consistency. Which values to pick is somewhat arbitrary (and not completely OS independent), I'd try convey the general meaning of my problem without being too specific.

You could take one of these (the comment would be `strerror`):

```
EIO          5  /* I/O error */
EINVAL      22  /* Invalid argument */
```

Being too specific with such a "fake" libc error could send people debugging a problem on the wrong track.

BTW I consulted [this list](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) for existing `errno`'s

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - I kind of hoped that there's a more structured approach than reading all errnos and picking the one which fits best (Structured in the way that different kinds errors call for different handling, e.g., with a timeout or CRC error, retrying make sense; for disk full error it doesn't). For the reference: In Python, the descriptions of the errnos list can retrieved with the ``os`` module by typing ``[(k,v, os.strerror(k)) for k,v in os.errno.errorcode.items()]``.